# wx.TextDropTarget not working in Linux

Tags: linux, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I have a desktop application developed with wxPython.  The applications runs fine under Windows and OSX (same codebase, no platform specific code).  Everything works on Linux except drag and drop. I can drag just fine, but DoDragDrop always returns wx.DragCancel.  I can however, drag from my application or to another app/desktop which excepts text and DoDragDrop returns wx.DragCopy.

It seems to me like the DropTargets aren't getting called. I've added debug statements to OnData, etc and they are never activated.

Has anyone seen this and know of a workaround?

Comment: I narrowed the problem down to the wx.StaticBoxSizer.  When my drop targets are contained within a StaticBoxSizer drop targets do not work! This seems to be specific to linux (I'm running ubuntu), as I have no problems with OSX/WindowsXP.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should include a minimal, functional piece of code reproducing your problem. Otherwise you probably will not get useful help. How could we know that your problem was on the StaticBoxSizer from your posted question ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a known issue in wxWidgets that was considered fixed, http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/2763, I am able to recreate this issue on linux. I reopened the ticket.

In the meantime you can swap your StaticBoxSizers or BoxSizers. or...

This works....
    parent = DropTargetCtrn.GetParent()
    boxes = [x for x in parent.GetChildren() if type(x)==wx.StaticBox]
    tmpParent = wx.Panel(parent)
    for box in boxes:
        box.Reparent(tmpParent)
        box.Reparent(parent)
    parent.Destroy()

This solution seems to lower the StaticBox in the window hierarchy so it don't interfere with drop events. Note, box.Lower() does not work.